# Server alias fails in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a server with an alias which I'm referencing in a stored procedure when trying to bulk load the contents of a text file into a temp table (as below). I get the following error message when the stored procedure is called:

> Cannot bulk load because the file "\\ServerAlias\SubFolder\FileName.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3 (The system cannot find the path specified.).

Yet when I swap out the alias for the real server name, the stored procedure runs fine. The alias works perfectly well in every other context in our system and I haven't found any answers online. Why won't it work here?

```
BULK INSERT #Temp
FROM '\\ServerAlias\SubFolder\FileName.txt'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 1,
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Comment: Is the server alias a DNS entry? And if you type `\\ServerAlias\SubFolder\` into Windows Explorer, does the folder open?

Comment: Yes, it's a DNS entry and it does resolve in Explorer without issue.

Comment: Does the DNS Entry resolve correctly when accessed from the server as well (such as if you remote in)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have credentials to remote into that server, but when I try it anyway using the alias, it does resolve to the actual server name when it gives me a permissions error.